# PHP str_repeat don't work with just the space character

Tags: php, string, echo, repeat

This is working by adding a space and a dot:

```
echo str_repeat(' .', $max-$i);
```

But this is not adding anything:

```
echo str_repeat(' ', $max-$i);
```

And I am 100% sure that the `$max-$i` is not 0, because just by adding a dot or a character after that space it will add the space and that character.

Comment: Echoing a bunch of spaces will show __nothing__

Comment: How are you viewing the output? If it's in a browser, it will collapse all of the spaces to one.

Comment: FYI: if you view the page source, it will show the spaces. You need to use `&nbsp`, as Jay's answer shows, in order to make the spaces visible in the browser. Keep in mind that nbsp stands for "non breaking space", so that may affect your text output.

Comment: If this is for spacing in a HTML document, it may be better to use CSS.

Comment: I add this spaces before some string text, so I can see if the text is at the edge of the output box or have some space before it

Comment: @u_mulder wrong-o, the browser will show a single space. Whether or not the average,untrained eye can see it is a different story!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML character string:

```
echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', $max-$i);
```

Comment: @AlinDincă You can also use `<pre>` for preformatted text